# Spring Caching key generator

Tags: spring, caching, spring-cache

I just have started working on Spring caching.

My service method is...

```
@Override
@Cacheable(value="profile", **key**="personId" )
public String cpuService2(Long personId, String personAddress){
    return "CachedMessage";
}
```

Without key clause, does not throw exception and assumes both parameters to autogenerate for cacheing
but with key, When I call this method, throws exception as...

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Field or property 'personId' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheExpressionRootObject'
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:246)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:112)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:107)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.OpGT.getValueInternal(OpGT.java:37)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.OpGT.getValueInternal(OpGT.java:29)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:102)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:98)
        at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.ExpressionEvaluator.condition(ExpressionEvaluator.java:99)
        at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport$CacheOperationContext.isConditionPassing(CacheAspectSupport.java:462)
        at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport$CacheOperationContext.isConditionPassing(CacheAspectSupport.java:456)
        at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.inspectCacheables(CacheAspectSupport.java:292)
        at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:199)
        at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:66)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
        at $Proxy5.cpuService3(Unknown Source)
        at pack100_cache.pack020CacheKey.TestSimpleBean.main(TestSimpleBean.java:34)
```

Searched documentation but no clue.  Hope somebody will address this concern.

Answer (score 9):

You're missing the # in front of `personId`

```
@Override
@Cacheable(value="profile", key="#personId" )
public String cpuService2(Long personId, String personAddress){
    return "CachedMessage";
}
```

The [caching abstraction chapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html) has numerous examples of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks.  Was referring to some blog with wrong code.

Comment: For me, after giving only single inverted comma it worked,  key="'#personId'"

Comment: I doubt it does, that's using `#personId` as the key (literally, that won't apply the spel expression)

Answer (score 5):

When things get more complicated SpEL perhaps is not the ideal solution when it comes to easy comprehension of the algorithm used to generate the key.
You might consider to use Java for generating the key:

```
@Component
public class FooGenerator implements KeyGenerator {
    @Override
    public Object generate(Object target, Method method, Object... params) {
        String param = "";

        if (params.length == 2) {
            if (params[0] instanceof String) {
                param = (String) params[0];

        String key = "FooKeyEquatesTo" + param;
        return key;
}
```

Then you can wire in this keygenerator where you need it:

```
@Cacheable(value = "nameofmycachearea", keyGenerator="fooGenerator")
```

Comment: hello! can you help me please? I'm sorry to write here. 
I have problem with building my custom keyGenerator. 
How do I get the method getAllEntities() without parameters  returned by the key "someKey"? (I have the last question in my profile)